# mqtt.js does not queue more than 65535 publish messages

Tags: node.js, mqtt, iot

I've been trying to use  https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt to simulate a large number of publishes and found that the queue does not hold more than 65535 messages at a time. (If I try to send more, the remaining are discarded) Is there a reason for this and are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that is the maximum number of packet ids allowed in the MQTT [spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718025)

Packet ids are a 16bit number (max 65535) and must be unique for all inflight messages.

> SUBSCRIBE, UNSUBSCRIBE, and PUBLISH (in cases where QoS > 0) Control
>   Packets MUST contain a non-zero 16-bit Packet Identifier
>   [MQTT-2.3.1-1]. Each time a Client sends a new packet of one of these
>   types it MUST assign it a currently unused Packet Identifier
>   [MQTT-2.3.1-2]. If a Client re-sends a particular Control Packet, then
>   it MUST use the same Packet Identifier in subsequent re-sends of that
>   packet. The Packet Identifier becomes available for reuse after the
>   Client has processed the corresponding acknowledgement packet. In the
>   case of a QoS 1 PUBLISH this is the corresponding PUBACK; in the case
>   of QoS 2 it is PUBCOMP. For SUBSCRIBE or UNSUBSCRIBE it is the
>   corresponding SUBACK or UNSUBACK [MQTT-2.3.1-3]. The same conditions
>   apply to a Server when it sends a PUBLISH with QoS > 0 [MQTT-2.3.1-4].